# How do I get an input with v-model to update when the Vue route changes?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have the following code:

https://jsfiddle.net/audiodude/pq9aczdu/33/

If you go to the Item View, then jump to page 10, say, it displays "page 10 of ??" (you're on page 10) and the input box agrees.

If you jump to page 20, same thing, so far so good.

However, if you then use the back button in your browser, it says "page 10 of ??" but the input box still says page 20.

I know that the Vue Router likes to reuse components when the path doesn't change, and my understanding is that the "this.page" data value on the ItemPagination component isn't getting updated. But I thought I was following good practice by separating the `initialPage` prop from the data that is bound to the model.

How do I get the input box to update on the browser BACK action? I can't use onBeforeRouteUpdate on ItemPagination because it's not the top level component being rendered so never receives that event.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your `ItemPagination` component to keep an eye on changes to the route and query parameters

```js
watch: {
  $route (to) {
    this.page = to.query.page || 1
  }
}
```

See https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes

Comment: Thanks! I somehow thought that beforeRouteUpdate was the only way to do it.